# TypeError: float() argument required to be a string or a number

Tags: python

I'm in Grade 11 Computer Science at my highschool, and I'm just starting out in Python. I'm supposed to make a function called `computepay` that will ask the user their name, their wage, and their hours that week and automatically calculate the total, including any overtime and not error out when an incorrect input is included. I made different functions for all the inputs, but when I plug it all into my `computepay` function it tells me this:

> TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number

```
def mainloop():  #Creating a loop so it doesn't error out.
    response = input('Make another calculation?[y/n]')  #inputing loop

    if response == 'n':   #creating input for n
        return

    if response == 'y':
        computepay()
    else:
        print("\n")
        print ("Incorrect input. .")
        mainloop()
def getname():
    name = input ("What's your name?")  #input of name

def getwage():
    wage = input ("Hello there! How much money do you make per hour?") #input
    try:
        float(wage)  #Making it so it does not error out when a float
    except:
            print ("Bad Input")
            getwage()

def gethours():
    hours = input ("Thanks, how many hours have you worked this week?")
    try:
            float(hours)  #Making it so it does not error out when a float
    except:
            print("Bad Input")
            gethours()

def computepay():
    name = getname()
    wage = getwage()
    hours = gethours()

    if float(hours) > float(40):
            newhours = float(hours) - float (40)  #figuring out the amount of overtime hours the person has worked
            newwage = float (wage) * float (1.5)  #figuring out overtime pay
            overtimepay = float (newwage) * float (newhours)  #calculating overtime total
            regularpay = (float(40) * float (wage)) + overtimepay  #calculating regular and overtime total.

            print (name,",you'll have made $",round(regularpay,2),"this week.")
    else:
            total = float(wage) * float(hours)
            print (name,",you'll have made $",round (total,2),"this week.")

    mainloop()  #creating the loop.

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

computepay()
```

Comment: It's a little confusing to see what's going on because the code formatting it off but the error message gives you a hint for what to look for - 'TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number'. In one of your calls to float ( eg float(wages) ) the thing you're passing in (say, wages) can't be converted to a number.

I'd suggest that you print out each of the variables to see what's in them - so, after `wage = getwage()` add another line `print(wage)`

Answer (score 1):

None of these functions are returning anything

```
name = getname()    
wage = getwage()    
hours = gethours()
```

So they all end up being `None`

Try this

```
def getname():
    return input("What's your name?")  # input of name

def getwage():
    wage = input("Hello there! How much money do you make per hour?")  # input
    return float(wage)

def gethours():
    hours = input("Thanks, how many hours have you worked this week?")
    return float(hours)
```

Answer (score 1):

What the error message is telling you is that *somewhere* (on the line number reported in the part of the error message that you didn't show us) you are calling `float` and giving it an argument (i.e. an input) that is neither a number, nor a string.

Can you track down where this is happening?

Hint: Any Python function which doesn't return anything (with the `return` keyword) implicitly returns `None` (which is neither a string nor a number).